# Problema al validar barcos en juego de hundir la flota

Tags: php

Estoy intentando crear el juego de hundir la flota, guardando los barcos en arrays. Quiero hacer una tabla en la que los cuadrantes con barco se diferencien (mediante `class`). El problema es que al comprobar solo me reconoce la primera casilla.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php

$lancha=array(71);
$destructor=array(18,28);
$submarino=array(33,43,53);
$portaaviones=array(75,76,77,78);
$barcos=array($lancha,$destructor,$submarino,$portaaviones);

session_start();
$_SESSION['barcos']=$barcos;

echo "<table>";
for($a=0;$a<10;$a++){
  echo "<tr>";
  for($b=0;$b<10;$b++){
    if(valida($a.$b))
      echo "<td class='verde'>".$a.$b."</td>";
    else if(valida($a.$b))
      echo "<td class='verde'>".$a.$b."</td>";
    else
      echo "<td>".$a.$b."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

function valida($p){
  foreach ($_SESSION['barcos'] as $key) {
    foreach ($key as $q => $value) {
      if($p==$value)
        return true;
      else
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: te invito a que edites tu codigo para poder entenderlo y uses las herramientas que se te proporcinan a la hora de formular una pregunta

Comment: Gracias, no sabia lo del código, soy nuevo por aquí.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la función `valida` y en cómo se devuelve `false` en concreto:

```
  foreach ($_SESSION['barcos'] as $key) {
    foreach ($key as $q => $value) {
      if($p==$value)
        return true;
      else
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Tal y como está puesto ahora mismo, se comprueba el primer elemento del array, si coincide: se devuelve `true`; y si no... se devuelve `false` parando las comprobaciones del resto de elementos del array. La solución entonces sería mover el `return false;` al final de la función en lugar de tenerlo como un `else` para que así sólo se devuelva `false` una vez comprobados todos los posibles elementos del array:

```
  foreach ($_SESSION['barcos'] as $key) {
    foreach ($key as $q => $value) {
      if($p==$value)
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

Con ese cambio, el código quedaría así y ya funciona:

```
<?php

$lancha=array(71);
$destructor=array(18,28);
$submarino=array(33,43,53);
$portaaviones=array(75,76,77,78);
$barcos=array($lancha,$destructor,$submarino,$portaaviones);

session_start();
$_SESSION['barcos']=$barcos;

echo "<table>";
for($a=0;$a<10;$a++){
  echo "<tr>";
  for($b=0;$b<10;$b++){
    if(valida($a.$b))
      echo "<td class='verde'>".$a.$b."</td>";
    else if(valida($a.$b))
      echo "<td class='verde'>".$a.$b."</td>";
    else
      echo "<td>".$a.$b."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

function valida($p){
  foreach ($_SESSION['barcos'] as $key) {
    foreach ($key as $q => $value) {
      if($p==$value)
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Como nota aparte, en `if(valida($a.$b)) ... else if(valida($a.$b)) ...`  la condición del `if` y del `else if` es la misma, por lo que nunca se entrará en el cuerpo del `else if`. ¿Querías hacer `if(valida($b.$a))` o algo diferente?